# I can't create a staggered transition delay in Javascript using a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a staggered transition delay for a HTML collection in JavaScript and cannot do it using a "for" loop. The HTML collection is stored in a variable called listItem.

This is the code I am currently using, and this DOES work:

```
listItem[0].style.transitionDelay = "0s";
listItem[1].style.transitionDelay = "0.1s";
listItem[2].style.transitionDelay = "0.2s";
listItem[3].style.transitionDelay = "0.3s";
```

I am trying to do the above using a "for" loop. I currently have this, and it does not work:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
listItem[i].style.transitionDelay = "i*0.1s";
}
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong with my "for" loop? The problem seems to reside with the "i*0.1s" value. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
listItem[i].style.transitionDelay = i*0.1+'s';
}`
can you try this?

Comment: thank you! this is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the multiplication outside of the quotes  and concatenate the result with the `"s"`

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   listItem[i].style.transitionDelay = i*0.1 + "s";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the multiply as number and then make it string.

You can do it with string interpolation using ES6:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  listItem[i].style.transitionDelay = `${i * 0.1}s`;
}
```